# What is the advantage of using ctrl-shift-t instead of ctrl-shift-r in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

When I first got into Java programming a mentor of mine introduced me to the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> shortcut in Eclipse, long before I discovered <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>. For that reason I had a bias towards <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and tended to use it whenever possible.

What I noticed eventually, though, was that if Eclipse had non class files in context <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> just didn't do anything, and I had to put a class file in context to use the shortcut.

Then it hit me that <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> is a catch-all shortcut which can open every file, no matter what the context in the IDE. So in all respects it seems to be a much more useful shortcut because it can be used at any time.

So that makes me wonder what I'm missing with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>. Outside of this shortcut pulling back a smaller subset of files when searching, is there any other advantage to using it that I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd> is for opening resources in the workspace (i.e. files)

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>t</kbd> is for opening classes (types), they may not be in files but in jars.

Comment: Ah ok, that seems to be what I'm missing.. ctrl shift t searches jars as well. Thanks for the answer.